# get date part only from datetime value using entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-5

I want to get date part only from database 'date time' value
I m using the below code..but it is getting date and time part.

```
using (FEntities context = new FEntities())
{
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
    if (context.tblvalue.Any(x => x.date == date))
    {    
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget mark selected answer for your questions.That will help other people to find the right answer .  It seems like you never selected answers for you questions.

Comment: this is  is not working on me.but I use  like below.now working..thank you
`x.date.Value.Date == date.Date`

Comment: `DateTime.Date` is not supported in EF until now, so I don't know how this can be working now for you.

Comment: @Gert Arnold, This is working code for me ` if (context.tblvalue.AsEnumerable().Any(x => x.date.Value.Date== date.Date))
                        {
}`

Comment: Yeah, `AsEnumerable()` makes everything work. But it's a very bad fix, because it pulls *all* `tblvalue` records into memory first.

Answer (score 34):

You can compare just specified parts:

```
context.tblvalue.Any(x => x.date.Year == data.Year 
                        && x.date.Month == data.Month 
                        && x.date.Day == data.Day);
```

**EDIT:**
You can also try the following:

```
context.tblvalue.Any(x => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.date) == data.Date);
```

**Another approach:**

```
context.tblvalue.Any(x =>  SqlFunctions.DatePart("year", x.date)  == data.Year 
                        && SqlFunctions.DatePart("month", x.date) == data.Month 
                        && SqlFunctions.DatePart("day", x.date)   == data.Day);
```

Comment: for this, which entity framework version I have to use.Now I can't use `x.date.Year==date.Year`

Comment: In more recent versions of EF, EntityFunctions is obsolete and has been replaced with "DbFunctions", but otherwise the second approach is very valid and what I use in these circumstances.

Comment: It is a shame that the old Linq2Sql is able to automatically translate `DateTime.Date` into an SQL expression appropriate for the database (e.g. `cast(d as date)` for SQL Server), but the new EF is not.

Answer (score 22):

With entity framework 6 and update use

```
context.tblvalue.Any(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.date) == data.Date);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<T>(sql, sql_parameters)
```

accepts pure SQL in the first parameter. 
Use MS SQL server's function
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), date_value, 112) AS MonthYYYYmm
for retrieving year with month.