# How to truncate time of DateTime in LINQ in Xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

**Goal**

Get all the entries for a certain day

**Query**

```
query = query.Where(s => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(s.Date) >= thisDay && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(s.Date) < nextDay);
```

**Problems**

1. Cannot use DbFunctions.TruncateTime cos apparently EntityFramework is not supported in Xamarin Android. Added Entity Framework but System.Data.Entity didn't appear.
2. Accessing the Date property for the DateTime object is not supported in the Where clause.

**Questions**

1. Is there a way to truncate the time in the query aside from using DbFunctions.TruncateTime()?
2. Anyone know of another way to achieve the goal without truncating the timestamp part from the object?

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30588033/get-date-part-only-from-datetime-value-using-entity-framework

Comment: "Accessing the Date property for the DateTime object is not supported in the Where clause"
rly?

Comment: Are you using Linq2Sql or Linq2Objects?

Answer (score -1):

Accessing the Date property for the DateTime object is not supported in the Where clause. -- this statement is wrong!!. It is accessible and the simplest way to access the date.
Try it.

Comment: Apparently Entity Framework [does not support it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30588033/11683).

Answer (score -1):

If I understood what you're trying to achieve, `DateTime.Date` is your guy.

> **Property value**
>   Type: System.DateTime
>   A new object with the same date as this instance, and the time value set to 12:00:00 midnight (00:00:00).

Comment: Apparently Entity Framework [does not support it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30588033/11683).

Comment: OP named LINQ, not EF. He stated he's trying to use an EF function (`DbFunction`)  but he also stated that *'apparently EntityFramework is not supported in Xamarin Android'*. So we're searching for something else. `DateTime.Date` is part of the standard .net framework.

Comment: Hmm yes, you are correct in that they do not appear to be using EF. Still, it does not matter that `DateTime.Date` is part of the standard .NET framework because it might very well be that Mono's implementation of Linq2Sql does not support translating `Where(d.Date == adate)` into SQL either.

Comment: Yes, but again he spoke about LINQ, not Linq2Sql.

Comment: Then they would have not had problems and would have not said *Accessing the Date property for the DateTime object is not supported in the Where clause.* Still, [let's ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41690649/how-to-truncate-time-of-datetime-in-linq-in-xamarin-android#comment70580177_41690649).