# Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is not a delegate type error

Tags: c#, linq

Whats wrong in my code ?
getting error "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is not a delegate type" and "Cannot convert query expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type"

```
Public List<Track> FillGridByDrId(DateTime? fromdate, DateTime? todate ,int DoctorId)
    {
        string today = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");

        var clinicid = BranchId;
        var track= (from td in db.table join pt in db.table2 on td.dataequals pt.data where (m => Convert.ToDateTime(m.time).Date >= fromdate&& Convert.ToDateTime(m.time).Date <= todate && m.id== id)
                            select new Appointment_Track
                            {
                                data=td.data
                            }
                           ).ToList();
        return track;
    }
```

Comment: I think `Convert.ToDateTime` is culprit. Can you try without converting

Comment: You cannot mix query and method syntax - use `where Convert.ToDateTime(td.AppTime).Date >= fromdate
             && Convert.ToDateTime(td.AppTime).Date <= todate && td.ClinicId == clinicid)`

Comment: Of course, as this looks like Entity Framework, most of your `where` clause won't work anyway.

Comment: You can not use `DateTime.Convert` in `linq` query unless `AppTime` col type was `Datetime`

Comment: thx @StephenMuecke its working.. But getting another exception "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: Like I told in my last comment, you cant use it.

Comment: @Aria yes that col type is Datetime only still getting error

Comment: That is because `Convert.ToDateTime()` cannot be translated to a sql query. But why are you needing that - your `AppTime` should be `DateTime` (and if its not, you have far more serious issues)

Comment: So why you want to cast it to `Datetime` again ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get date part only from datetime value using entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30588033/get-date-part-only-from-datetime-value-using-entity-framework)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
where (m => Convert.ToDateTime(m.AppTime).Date >= fromdate
         && Convert.ToDateTime(m.AppTime).Date <= todate && m.ClinicId == clinicid)
```

should perhaps be:

```
// Straight after var clinicid = CmsHelper.BranchId;
var todatenextday = todate.AddDays(1);

// then replace your non-working code with 
where td.AppTime >= fromdate
         && td.AppTime < todatenextday  && td.ClinicId == clinicid
```

You generally want to avoid using `Convert.ToDateTime` in Entity Framework since EF doesn't know how to translate it to SQL. But if you want any `DateTime` that is today or tomorrow, for example, then you need to check whether the `DateTime` is greater than or equal to the start of today **and** less than the start of two days in the future. That is what the above code does (through the use of `AddDays`).

Also, depending on how you use `today`, you may wish to consider changing:

```
string today = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

to:

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
```

since  it may be best to deal with `DateTime` directly.